# Uncaught referenceError : Undefined variable , even I set it to global

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a POST request using jQuery which receives an array with values. I want to loop through the array and add it into the options field.

I successfully added the values into a variable as a string, but when I try to access those variables it returns the error:

> Uncaught referenceError : Undefined variable

It does this even though I set it to global.

```js
function addHub() {
  drivers = "";
  var totalHubs = $("#totalHubs").val();

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('getDriverList') }}",
    method: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery.each(data.driverName, function(i, val) {
        drivers += "<option value='" + val + "'> " + val + "</option>";
      });
      for (i = 1; i <= totalHubs; i++) {
        console.log(drivers);
      }
```

Comment: You're not really declaring your `drivers` variable. It doesn't have either `var`, `let` or `const` before it.

Comment: tried it too. doesnt help

Comment: have you tried using JSON.parse ?

Comment: The `i` variable in your `for` loop isn't properly declared either

Comment: However I can able to loop through it . it prints pretty other variables. I just used i to loop

Comment: The error is because of this line: ```jQuery.ajax({```. Change it to ```$.ajax({```

Comment: can you show us the full error message, so we can know the name of the variable that is being problematic?

Comment: FYI: It is Not Recommended to declare a variable without var keyword. It can accidentally overwrite an existing global variable. The scope of the variables declared without a var keyword becomes global irrespective of where it is declared. Global variables can be accessed from anywhere on the web page.

Comment: @henokg There is no error message at all. After storing the sring in `drivers` ,  First `console.log` after `jquery.each()` prints the string. But Inside the `foreach()` , I cant able to view the `drivers` string .

Comment: just before your for loop check the value of totalHubs and drivers.

Comment: @eduard You are probably running in strict mode. Hence the error `Uncaught referenceError`.  If you follow the suggestions in the above comments the error will definitely go away. Use var/let to declare the variables  https://codepen.io/nithinthampi/pen/yLLbrWN. You can see the console log printed in the codepen

Comment: `The error is because of this line: jQuery.ajax({. Change it to $.ajax({` That is not true at all.